# Automatically clicking a hyperlink on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have a hyperlink in my jsp.
When we click on this, a popup overlay gets displayed and the background greys out. After closing the popup, the background becomes normal.
Now I want the hyperlink to be clicked automatically when the page loads.
Can anyone say how we can do that?

I tried the following..

```
$('#ViewOutages').click(); , 
$('#ViewOutages').click();
```

but none of it worked.. `ViewOutages` is the div id in which the hyperlink is present.

Can someone please help on this.

Comment: Do you want a link to be clicked specifically or a popup to be shown?

Comment: `$('#ViewOutages').find('#linkID').click();`

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload=function(){
 if(document.getElementById('test')!=null||document.getElementById('test')!=""){ 
 document.getElementById('test').click();
 }
}
```

This actually worked.. :)

Answer (score 1):

use [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#ViewOutages').trigger('click');
})
```

from

> 'ViewOutages' is the div id in which the hyperlink is present.

looks like your `<a>` is inside the div ..i assume you need to use `find()` or `children()`

```
$(function(){
  $('#ViewOutages').find('#linkID').trigger('click');
 })
```

Comment: +1, though if the original task is to show a popup - I would show it with some explicit code, not by triggering a link that does the same (but seems like an OP isn't interested in a more straightforward solution)

Comment: No need for `trigger` as [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) without parameters is a shortcut to `.trigger('click')`: `This method is a shortcut for .on('click', handler) in the first two variations, and .trigger('click') in the third.` Just saying...

Comment: I tried >>$$('#ViewOutages').find('#testbutton').trigger('click');
  "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: >$('#ViewOutages').find('#testbutton').trigger('click');
  "'null' is null or not an object"

Comment: I tred this in Developer tool of IE

Comment: @Phanimadhavi Vasantala: do you understand what the code does or just blindly copy-paste it? How exactly a click handler shows a popup?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ViewOutages").trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Point is try to follow the standards as mentioned in [.ready() API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). `$().ready(handler)` is not recommended and `$('document').ready(handler)` is not even mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('#ViewOutages').find('a').trigger('click');
    // if hyperlink is in div#ViewOutages as you said in question
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use $(document).ready(); function which is same as